# Why are all these fragments receiving the same bundle items?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I'm trying to add Fragments to a view. I have a String Array and I would like to create a new fragment for each one. Seems like a simple task.

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("category", items[i]);
    Fragment frag = new MyFragment();
    frag.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.mga_viewParentContainer, frag, "frag_" + i);
    ft.commit();

    Log.i ("FT commit called on item:", items [i]);

} // for loop
```

This creates a new fragment for every item in the array, however every fragment is getting the "category" bundle item from the last item in the array. So all fragments inflate the same info.

However, the Log reports all items as theyes should be.

Why is this happening?

Comment: try giving different key for bundle

Comment: Then I need to on check all keys in fragment to know what info to gather

Comment: @jb15613 your code works well when I tried it. Where did you check the bundle inside the fragment?

Comment: I grab in during OnCreateView. I think my IDE is brain farting